# PHP, Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) on SECOND query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mariadb

I'm trying to migrate an elder and quite simple PHP application to a new server with very limited success.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

$query1 = "select field1 from table2 where anotherfield < 3";
$res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);
$row_one = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res1);

// do something with result in $row_one and maybe loop through results

$query2 = "select field2 from table2 where anotherfield = 'somevalue'";
// the next one is going to fail
$res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);
$row_two = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2);

// do something with $res1 and $res2
```

The first mysqli_query runs fine. I get records and can do something on them. Then I need another result from another query to go on, but the second query to the same connection throws this "Access denied" error.

No problem as long as I do just ONE query.

You might guess that I previously had "mysql" instead of "mysqli" in this code, which is true. The weird thing is, that I still have the old code running on an old server which is fine connecting to its old MySQL. If I point it to the new MySQL (MariaDB) on the new server, the same old code shows the same "one query only" problem. I initially thought the old PHP 5 was not able to properly talk to the new MariaDB and PHP 7 will do, but it's exactly the same there.

My guess is with some quirks on the Database and not with the PHP part, as these consecutive queries SHOULD work. Should they still work?

I already checked for "max_connections" entries in the DB config file and in the user privileges without spotting something unusual, but maybe I just dont't know what to look for.

On the other hand, the very web/DB server runs other PHP/MySQL applications quite fine without any hickup. Everything but my piece of code.

I'm quite sure I miss something trivial and elementary.

Comment: The code you left out might be more relevant. A mysqli_close you forgot to mention? Also why in gods name mysqli and not PDO? (Just slapping on an `i` is not a senseful migration strategy.)

Comment: I agree with @mario, you must have made an error in the code you omitted from the question.

Comment: For now I just want a "migration to new server", not a complete application redesign, so mysqli seems the quicker way to get it running again. No "msqli_close" here. I need both result sets further down.

The code example is not really all, but almost. It's really in the first few lines of code where the problem emerges.

When the problem is "by design" (noone would do this nowadays), then how could I avoid doing several consecutive queries?

Comment: This behaviour is not by design, you must be making some error somewhere.

Comment: im not an expert at this but maybe fetch the first result set into an array of arrays or something in memory and close that result set before trying the second query?

Comment: @RobertOrso in response to your *"Should they still work?"* - Have you tried it? did you check for errors at all for the php and on the queries? I don't see any of that in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mario and Shadow, you guided me the right way. The certain knowledge that this kind of query definitely looks right and should work put my focus on the database again.

So here it goes...

It turned out that "table2" in the above example was not a table but a VIEW. No inherent problem with this, if not the original definition had been lazy and bad in the old database (before migration):

```
CREATE 
  ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED 
  DEFINER=`root`@`` 
  SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `table2` AS ...
```

But there is no user "root@" in the database, it has never been and nobody could ever define one. We have "root@localhost" and we have "user@%".

The old MySQL obviously silently interpreted that as "root@%' or similar and the select went well. The new one picks the "SQL SECURITY DEFINER", looks up the privileges of "`root`@``" and correctly fails with "Access Denied".

I redesigned the view as the database owner with the correct "user@localhost" and additionally with "SQL SECURITY **INVOKER**", in case anyone else might open the query to make sure the table privileges are used.

There have been a handful of those bad views in between lots of correctly defined ones and I picked a bad one by chance as the "second" one each time.

Easy fix, once you know about it.